# How to safely edit this 3 column flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to edit this layout I found on internet but it is in CSS flex and I know nothing about flex, but only normal old css.

How to edit it safely without damaging the code?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

.header,
.footer {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: #34495e;
}

.content-body {
  /*   flex: 1 1 auto; */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* equla to: height: calc(100vh - 100px); */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.content-body .content {
  /*   flex: 1 1 auto; */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* width: calc(100% - 200px); */
  overflow: auto;
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.content-body .sidenav,
.content-body .ads {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-body .sidenav {
  background: #e74c3c;
}

.content-body .ads {
  background: #e67e22;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <div class="content-body">
    <nav class="sidenav">This must be deleted</nav>
    <main class="content">Content</main>
    <aside class="ads">Aside</aside>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

I also created a Codepen
https://codepen.io/familias/pen/WNYQeqQ

What I need is:
to safely delete the left sidebar, marked with the text "This must be deleted" and leave middle part like this:
`<main class="content">Content</main>`
100% width
`<aside class="ads">Aside</aside>`
100px width

I tried myself but it does not displayed good on mobile device

Comment: [Removed sidebar](https://jsfiddle.net/umgxL6t8/), you want to change the middle part into 2 equal parts, "Content" and "Aside"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the `sidenav` element and the associated css. The propoerty `flex: 0 0 100px` sets the `flex-grow` to 0 (i.e. don't grow) and `flex-shrink` to 0 (i.e. don't get smaller, and the `flex-basis` to 100px, i.e. keep it at 100px wide.

[Here's](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/) an explainer on CSS tricks

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u044iM9xsWU) by Kevin Powell is a good starter for flexbox.

Hope this helps.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /*padding: 0; body has no padding by default so removed this*/
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

.header,
.footer {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: #34495e;
}

.content-body {
  /*   flex: 1 1 auto; */
  flex-grow: 1; /* equla to: height: calc(100vh - 100px); */
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: row;  this is default so removed it */
}

.content-body .content {
  /*   flex: 1 1 auto; */
  flex-grow: 1; /* width: calc(100% - 200px); */
  overflow: auto;
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.content-body .ads {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-body .ads {
  background: #e67e22;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <div class="content-body">
    <main class="content">Content</main>
    <aside class="ads">Aside</aside>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, it worked. But now I realize ii ts not responsive in mobile phones so I will need to find another solution :(

Comment: Maybe have a look at this video? https://youtu.be/p3_xN2Zp1TY